# Use several thread when rendering pdf to image using mupdf

Tags: multithreading, mupdf

Is it possible to run `mutool.exe draw` using several threads to increase PDF to Image conversion speed?
The command help list says something about `-B` and `-T` parameters, but I do not understand what maximum band_height does? What values should I set for `-B`?

```
-B -    maximum band_height (pXm, pcl, pclm, ocr.pdf, ps, psd and png output only)
-T -    number of threads to use for rendering (banded mode only)
```

Executing mutool with `-B 100 -T 6` slightly increased conversion speed by 10% but not so much, the CPU usage spiked from 6% to 11%, but why not 60%?

```
mutool.exe draw -r 300 -B 100 -T 6 -o "C:\test%d.png" "C:\test-large.pdf"
```

Answer (score 0):

Every system and PDF is different but lets use a single page without text for timings in my system.

I know ***[this file](https://github.com/sumatrapdfreader/sumatrapdf/files/3883100/ENR6.3-9.slow.rendering.pdf)*** is complex but not too unusual since without text, other objects behave as text would, without the complexity of font look-up etc. so rendering time is generally fairly similar for a given run.

Lets start with a low resolution since I know the file well enough to have found it fail due to Malloc in this machine around 300dpi.

```
mutool draw -Dst -r 50 -o complex.png complex.pdf
page complex.pdf 1 1691ms
total 1691ms (0ms layout) / 1 pages for an average of 1691ms
```

We can see using a PDF screen viewer timings, that's good as the screen render (which is **darn fast at 2 seconds for that 1 PDF page**) is about 96dpi

```
LoadDocument: 5.47 ms, 1 pages  
Slow rendering: 2035.27 ms, page: 1
```

```
mutool draw -Dst -r 100 -o complex.png complex.pdf
page complex.pdf 1 3299ms
total 3299ms (0ms layout) / 1 pages for an average of 3299ms

mutool draw -Dst -r 200 -o complex.png complex.pdf
page complex.pdf 1 7959ms
total 7959ms (0ms layout) / 1 pages for an average of 7959ms

mutool draw -Dst -r 400 -o complex.png complex.pdf
page complex.pdf 1error: malloc of 2220451350 bytes failed
error: cannot draw 'complex.pdf'
```

***So this is when "Banding" is required to avoid memory issues*** since my target is 400 dpi output.

You may see I used -D above so I need to remove that for threads, `cannot use multiple threads without using display list`. Lets start small since too large bands or too many threads can also malloc error.

```
mutool draw -st -B 32 -T 2 -r 400 -o complex.png complex.pdf
page complex.pdf 1 14111ms
total 14111ms (0ms layout) / 1 pages for an average of 14111ms
```

***14 seconds for this file is not a bad result*** based on the progressive timings above, but perhaps on this 8  thread device I could do better? Lets try bigger bands and more threads.

```
mutool draw -st -B 32 -T 3 -r 400 -o complex.png complex.pdf
page complex.pdf 1 12726ms
total 12726ms (0ms layout) / 1 pages for an average of 12726ms

mutool draw -st -B 256 -T 3 -r 400 -o complex.png complex.pdf
page complex.pdf 1 12234ms
total 12234ms (0ms layout) / 1 pages for an average of 12234ms

mutool draw -st -B 256 -T 6 -r 400 -o complex.png complex.pdf
page complex.pdf 1 12258ms
total 12258ms (0ms layout) / 1 pages for an average of 12258ms
```

So increasing threads up to 3 helps and upping the Band size helps, but 6 threads is no better. So is there another tweak we can consider, and playing around with many runs ***the best I got on this kit/configuration was 12 seconds.***

```
mutool draw -Pst -B 128 -T 4 -r 400 -o complex.png complex.pdf
page complex.pdf 1 1111ms (interpretation) 10968ms (rendering) 12079ms (total)
```